# resending $_POST variable

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have IPN handler on my page and I need to validate.

Validating is made by sending $_POST back to the paypal with adidional field cmd=_notify-validate.

and then check if it's content is VALIDATE.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the PayPal sample codes and directly deploy it to make the post-back validation.
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

The only thing you would need to customize in there is when the data's verified, parse the transaction data and implement your order management logic